# WCF webservice testing

Tags: json, web-services

I am new to test webservices.

Please provide some useful tool link to test webservices.

And also i need basic explanation of wcf webservices. how it works?

is it uses json format for data exchange?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create simple `Console Application` test client for WCF service and make service calls. Also setting breakpoints inside service methods will help you to `debug`.
2. You should go through beginner tutorials about WCF: [CodeProject link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406096/A-beginners-tutorial-for-understanding-Windows),
   [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx)
3. `XML` is default format for WCF, but you can switch to `JSON` using
   `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` or/and 
   `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` attributes.